# Sql Server - Count between two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following columns in two tables:

```
Table 1  
simultaneous type a  
10                 

Table 2 - records with type a

loginAAA type a  
loginBBB type a
```

What i need is a query that counts the two logins, how many "type a" they have and check if the quantity surpasses the table 1 restriction. And if possible, only return a count for the ones that do surpass the restriction.

I think i can do this easy with a cursor, but is there another way to check for this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to formulate an SQL query like this

```
 SELECT TypeID, restrictionTable.restriction, count(TypeID) as LoginCount
 FROM loginTable
       INNER JOIN restrictionTable 
            ON loginTable.TypeID = restrictionTable.TypeID
 GROUP BY TypeID, restriction
 HAVING count(TypeID) <= restrictionTable.restriction
```

But I'm not sure if I have properly understood how your tables are defined and related. Could you perhaps edit your question and - in particular - clarify the structure of table 1.

Comment: With the sample data i provided, what i want is that the query return the number 2 from the table 2 and then compares it to the number 10 in table 1. if possible, since 2 is lower than 10, no rows returned.

Comment: I modified my answer. It's untested code but I think you could use the idea